# How to remove duplicate history from a git repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I tried using a `git filter-branch` command I've seen in a related post to rename a batch of old commits. The result is that now my repo has a number of identical commits with different authors. It left me with the following scenario:

```
A' -> B' -> C'
               \
A  -> B  -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

`A'` is identical to `A` except for the commit author, and the same for `B'` and `C'`. I'd like to remove all references and history of `A'`, `B'`, and `C'`. Note: none of these commits are on a branch or have a tag.

How do I remove the duplicate commit history? This is the result I'm after:

```
A  -> B  -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

---

My reason for this is to simply clean up the history. I am the only one who touches this code, and I know this wouldn't be a good thing to attempt on any kind of non-trivial repo. Also, it seems as though there are many similar questions, but I can't seem to piece together a working solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Well, this almost worked. The only problem I see from this is that it overwrote the submission times for the most recent commits (D+).

---

It seems I've found a solution. I was dancing around it all day, but finally figured out the correct commits to reference. Going by my example above, I cloned a new repo with the latest master branch. From there I found the `C` commits' hash, which represents the last know good state. Then I run rebase in interactive mode:

```
git rebase -i <the C commits' hash>
```

In the editor that appears, only the duplicate commits that I wanted to delete appeared (up until current history). So I removed all the old duplicate entries up to the `D` commit. After saving the rebase command completed without error.

At this point my local repository seemed to have everything in order, so I forced it onto the server:

```
git push --force origin master
```

The end result seems to be exactly what I was looking for:

```
A  -> B  -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

Not sure if it is the best way, but then again this isn't really something you want to be doing.

Comment: +1 – don’t worry about the submission times. The author times still record when you created the commits. The “correct” way (that will also work on more complicated repos) is to use `git replace` or grafts and then run `git filter-branch`.